# Python get combination of continous words

Tags: python, list, combinations, python-itertools

I have a list like this:

```
tokens = ["hi", "how", "are", "you"]
```

I am trying to get combinations of words upto `n=3`
My expected output is:

```
output = [ ["hi"], ["hi", "how" ], ["hi", "how" , "are"], ["how"], ["how", "are"], ["how", "are", "you"], ["are"], ["are", "you"], ["you"]
```

My code:

```
comb = []
for i in range(3):
    comb += list(itertools.combinations(tokens,i+1))
```

but my code provides combinations of everything not only the next words. Waht is wrong here?

Comment: In this case, you need to make your own algorithm. `itertools` may not do the job.

Comment: You can use 2 loops by one to choose the start point and other for the length of the array and copy the array and store it in a new array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check if this code snippet solves your purpose, you can play around with this code:

```
import itertools
tokens = ["hi", "how", "are", "you"]

output = [tokens[start:end] for start, end in itertools.combinations(range(len(tokens)+1), 2)]
output
```

Output:

```
[['hi'], ['hi', 'how'], ['hi', 'how', 'are'], ['hi', 'how', 'are', 'you'], ['how'], ['how', 'are'], ['how', 'are', 'you'], ['are'], ['are', 'you'], ['you']]
```